# Custom to_json not being called in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

## Model

```
def to_json
  p 'ppp'
  p UNDISPLAYABLE_SIGNS
  if sign.in? UNDISPLAYABLE_SIGNS
    {code: code}
  else
    super
  end
end
```

## Controller

```
    render json: {currency: @currency, savedInUser: true}
```

ppp is not printed in server console, how could I customise my JSON response, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is as_json not to_json

```
def as_json
  p 'ppp'
  p UNDISPLAYABLE_SIGNS
  if sign.in? UNDISPLAYABLE_SIGNS
    {code: code}
  else
    super
  end
end
```